# How to join only one record from a related table with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In my rails application, I have two tables

| Member |
| --- |
| id |
| name |
| phone |

| Membership |
| --- |
| id |
| duration |
| start_date |
| member_id |

I'm trying to generate a query to join members with memberships but I only want the current membership which is the one with the most recent `start_date` for each member to be joined.

I came up with this

```rb
Member.joins(:memberships).merge(Membership.order(start_date: :desc).distinct(:member_id))
```

But it doesn't work and errors out with the message "(Object doesn't support #inspect)". Struggling with this, would really appreciate some help! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand why you need this, but maybe you wanted something like this:

```rb
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :current_membership, 
          class_name: 'Membership', 
          -> { order(start_date: :desc) }
end

Member.joins(:current_membership)
```

doc: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one